# How to add a validation error in MVC for a view model with multiple properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If I have a view model that looks something like this:

```
public class Car

{

     Wheel CarWheel {get;set;}
     Body CarBody {get;set;}

}
```

And my Wheel and Body classes look something like this:

```
public class Wheel
{
    int Number {get;set;}
    string WheelType {get;set;}
}

public class Body
{
    int Number {get;set;}
    string BodyType {get;set;}
}
```

And I want to add a model error for the wheel number being less than 1:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(???, "Error! You must have at least one wheel to avoid abrasion on your bottom");
```

How do I specify that the error is specifically with the Wheel class, and not the Body class?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To specify that the error is on the `CarWheel` version of `Number` and not `CarBody`, you'll need to "namespace" the value for the property name in the same way you would to get or set that property's value:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("CarWheel.Number", "Error! You must have at least one wheel to avoid abrasion on your bottom");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Car_CarWheel_Number", "Error! You must have at least one wheel to avoid abrasion on your bottom");
```

OR

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error! You must have at least one wheel to avoid abrasion on your bottom \n\r Error 2");
```

Comment: If you are using the standard Html.TextBoxFor, etc. generators, this will not work. The Naming convention there is Model.Property.

Answer (score 1):

Bryan's answer or you could try using data annotations.

The range attribute should work for you or you could write your own if need be.